# Flutter Cupertino DateTime Picker: how to remove transform tilt effect of wheel

Tags: flutter, datetime, picker, flutter-cupertino

I am using a flutter plugin called [flutter_cupertino_datetime_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_datetime_picker) and I want to modify the wheel to remove the curvature of the numbers (screenshot) and display it without transformation.

Now

[image]

Desired

[image]

By default it shows like the second screenshot but I have been modifying the plugin core to show custom, but the wheel shows like this

The widget is:

```
          Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 40.0),
                child: DateTimePickerWidget(
                  dateFormatSeparator: ':',
                  minDateTime: DateTime.parse(MIN_DATETIME),
                  maxDateTime: DateTime.parse(MAX_DATETIME),
                  initDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                  dateFormat: DATE_FORMAT,
                  minuteDivider: 1,
                  pickerTheme: const DateTimePickerTheme(
                      showTitle: false,
                      itemTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontFamily: Fonts.satoshi),
                      backgroundColor: AmbarColors.contentInverse),
                  onChange: (dateTime, selectedIndex) {
                    setState(() {
                      _dateTime = dateTime;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont provide that constants to us we cant reproduce your code.

but for now i tried that package and it seems related to date format on default its how you desired. So your problem relies on date format.

```dart
class _DemoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const _DemoWidget();

  @override
  State<_DemoWidget> createState() => __DemoWidgetState();
}

class __DemoWidgetState extends State<_DemoWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('InheritedWidget Demo'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: DateTimePickerWidget(
          dateFormatSeparator: ":",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And i didnt see any handle to configure that problem in constructor.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_date_picker you may try to use this package.

Comment: Thanks a lot, however I need to use this for a time picker separated by ":" and this package don't allow